# How to generate this pattern in C?

Tags: c

```
%@@@%
%...%
%...%
%...%
%@@@%
```

Where is my mistake? Please let me know. I am a beginner: I just started programming. I would appreciate your help.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
    int i,j,num;
    scanf("%d", &num);

    for(i=0;i<num;i++){
        for(j=0;j<num;j++){
            if((i==0)||(i==num-1)){
            printf("@");
            }
            else if((j==i-1)||(j==num-1)){
            printf("%");
            }
            else
                printf(".");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you write this code it only shows the @ and the dots but i cant figure it out how to put the %

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Kindly show your reseacrh / debugging effort so far. Please see the [ask] help page and [The perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) blog post by Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 1):

There are three problems in your code.

1. The the `%`symbol is an operator in C what is used for formatting in `printf` function. Therefore the `printf("%");` doesn't print this character. There is a trick, you can write `printf("%%");` instead.
2. First take care about the character `%` and then the character `@` in your evaluation, otherwise you can't get the `%`character in the first and last rows
3. The condition for variable `j` also must be equal to `0` or `num-1`

There is an even more elegant solution but to follow your code this is the right implementation:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
   int i,j,num;
   scanf("%d", &num);

   for(i=0;i<num;i++)
   {
      for(j=0;j<num;j++)
      {
         if((j==0)||(j==num-1))
         {
            printf("%%");
         }
         else if((i==0)||(i==num-1))
         {
            printf("@");
         }
         else
         {
            printf(".");
         }
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I suggest to rethink your code. Have fun. :-)

Comment: or `putchar('%');`